# jquery Autocomplete does not show float datatype values

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am retrieving some multi column data in my jquery autocomplete . Everything is working fine but the problem is autocomplete shows only those values which does not contain float or double value. for ex- if product name is jquery 2.0 then it retrieves(or shows) only jquery 2
    I tried formatting query of my web service like this

```
select format(ProductName , '0.00') as ProductName, ProductCode, format(Mrp,'0.00') as Mrp,PackingName,format(SaleRate,'0.00') as SalesRate ,SchemeRatio  from ProductMaster where " & "ProductName like @SearchText + '%'
```

But it did not change anything.
What change do i need to do , please help, Thanks in advance!

here is my jquery code

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {

       $("#<%#txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {
               $.ajax({
                   url: '<%#ResolveUrl("~/Service.asmx/GetCustomers") %>',
                   data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   success: function (data) {
                       var safe = data
                       response($.map(safe.d, function (item) {

                           return {
                               label: item.split('.')[0],
                               value: item.split('-')[0]

                           }

                       }))


                   },
                   error: function (response) {
                       alert(response.responseText);
                   },
                   failure: function (response) {
                       alert(response.responseText);
                   }
               });
           },
           select: function (e, i) {

               $("#<%#hfProductId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.value);
           },
           minLength: 1,

       });

       $("#<%#txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete().data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
           var line_item = '';
           line_item += "<a><div class='search_row'>";
           line_item += "<div class='sku'>Product Name-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + item.label.split('-')[0] + "</div>" + "<div class='productcode'>Product Code-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + item.label.split('-')[1] + "</div>" + "<div class='sku'>Product Mrp-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + item.label.split('-')[2] + "</div>" + "<div class='sku'>Packing Name-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + item.label.split('-')[3] + "</div>" + "<div class='sku'>Scheme Ratio-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + item.label.split('-')[4] + "</div>";
           line_item += "<hr>";

           line_item += "</div></a>";

           return $("<li>")
           .append(line_item)
           .appendTo(ul);
       };

 });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nyoman - its a very silly mistake that i did , i am splitting every record with split('.') , thats why i was not getting the next digits , i just changed my code

```
 response($.map(safe.d, function (item) {

                       return {
                           label: item.split('.')[0],
                           value: item.split('-')[0]

                       }
```

to

```
 response($.map(safe.d, function (item) {

                       return {
                           label: item.split('^')[0],
                           value: item.split('-')[0]

                       }
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply the function on the jquery side..

for example

```
parseFloat(yourValue).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: i tried but it is now showing NaN , though all values are numbers. here is my jquery code '  line_item += "<p>" + item.label.split('-')[0] + "</p>" + "<p>" + parseFloat("item.label.split('-')[1]").toFixed(2) + "</p>" + "<p>" + item.label.split('-')[2] + "</p>" + "<p>" + item.label.split('-')[3] + "</p>" + "<p>" + item.label.split('-')[4] + "</p>";'

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, please post your webservice code